# Update Dart DevTools

Tags: flutter, dart, devtools

I'm currently on `flutter 1.22.4` with dart devtools on `0.9.3+4`, but `https://pub.dev/packages/devtools/install` has it at `0.9.5`. My current version doesn't have the response body in the network tab and I'm trying to update to a newer version and I don't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

First, run flutter -doctor and see if there are any errors. Then try running "flutter pub get" if that doesn't do the trick upgrade your tools and run flutter -clean and try again.

Comment: In that case try using flutter pub upgrade, but be careful with the other dependencies of the dart pacakges

Comment: Tried that also, no change.